# Does VB.NET offer any performance improvement over VB6 for CPU-bound processes?

Tags: vb.net, performance, vb6, vb6-migration

I'm working on a mathematical model written in VB6. The amount of CPU time this model is consuming is becoming a concern to some of our customers and the notion has been floated that porting it to VB.NET will improve its performance.

The model is performing a lot of single-precision arithmetic (a finite-difference scheme over a large grid) with small bursts of database access every five seconds or so (not enough to be important). Only basic arithmetic functions with occasional use of the ^ 4 operator are involved.

Does anyone think porting to VB.NET is likely to improve matters (or not)? Does anyone know any reliable articles or papers I can check over to help with this decision?

Comment: Can't see a reason why a straight convert (in as much as it will) would give you a significant performance improvement. Reworking teh algorithm with the added language an framework features available in net, almost certainly given a sound optimistion strategy. But on that basis you could probably optimise it in VB6, except for threading.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: Should be an answer, not a comment ;-)

Comment: I think I'd ask the person "floating the notion" to provide some data do back it up.  That sounds more like a "hopeful guess" to me.

Comment: Not confident enough to put it forward as an answer, in fact without seeing the app, and possibly having a play not sure there is an "answer" to this question.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and comments. The consensus seems to be, probably very little difference, which is (I must admit) what I suspected.

Comment: I assume you've tried the VB6 compiler optimization options  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263483(v=vs.60).aspx. Target native code, optimize for fast code, remove floating point error checks, etc?

Comment: @MarkJ, thanks for the tip, but I have got it compiled that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My opinion is that VB.Net won't improve performance by far. The improvement is given by your ability to make an optimized algorith.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best performance boost you can get is eliminating the DB access (even if it doesnt look important I/O usually is the bottleneck, not the language itself). If possible  get the data upfront and save it at the end instead of accesing every 5 secs.

Also as other pointed out, change the algorithm if possible since porting the code to .NET probably will only get you small **performance** benefits.

But if you change it to .NET 4.0 maybe you can use the parallel extensions and really get a boost by using multiple cores. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx , but that also means, changing the algorithm

Hope it helps. ;-)

Comment: Parallel extensions might be good. But the question appears to indicate that db access is only taking a small fraction of execution time, and even if you optimized the db access to zero time, it would only be a small speed-up overall. I/O is not usually the bottleneck in a mathematical model of the type described in the question. You can't generalize and say I/O is always the bottleneck in every program

Comment: @MarkJ Thats why i said "usually is the bottleneck". Anyway, accesing to a DB is probably slower than any "basic arithmetic function". Accessing a DB is VERY time consuming and doing it in small intervals is even worst because stops the program calculations.(unless is done using another thread) There is the LAN lag, disk access, creating queries, processing results... compared to just some "simple" math as Brian points out is doing. And usually is the bottleneck not for being the more time consuming, it is for stoping execution for x amount of time every x seconds.

Comment: Just to be clear, do a for loop that does some simple math inside. And then do the same loop and calculations but accesing a DB on each iteration. And then a version that access at the begining, and the end only. Im pretty sure is not going to be a small speed up. ;-)

Comment: Brian says "only basic arithmetic functions are used" not "it's only simple math". He's doing simple operations (e.g. add, subtract, multiply and divide) but he's doing *a freaking lot* of them. What I call **"complicated math"** :) Just so I can be clear, stopping execution for x seconds every y seconds is only significant if x is about the same size as y. If x is (say) 0.2 seconds and y is 5 seconds. A simple for loop, spending 0.2 seconds accessing a DB (x) and 5 seconds doing math (y). Then even if you make the DB access *infinitely fast*, 0 seconds, your overall speedup is `0.2/5.2 = 4%`.

Comment: Is relative of course, but what happens when the user gets a faster CPU? Then you are loosing a bigger % because the data access will take the same time and the calculations a lot less. So, my point is that the algorithm is less eficient this way. (but maybe it has to be this way) And what im saying is that just changing the programming language is not going to affect as much as removing data access (that is recurrent and time expensive), since we dont know much more about what it does.

Comment: Also it depends if the database is on the same machine, the clients access a remote server and how distant it is, wich kind of connection, etc... But in my own experience reducing DB access tends to be the easiest way to improve performance and the most noticable. ;-)  But as always, it all depends on the machine, algorithms, network, data, etc. of each specific case.

Answer (score 1):

I think that improvements in memory management improve performance in VB.NET

Answer (score 1):

To provide you with a correct answer we should check your code...

But certainly VB.NET in theory should be more performant:

1. possibility to compile on 64 bit machines (without too much effort)
2. VB6 was interpreted, VB.NET is almost compiled
3. You can use threads (depends on your algorithm) and other "tricks", so you can use more CPUs to make calculations in parallel

Best thing to try: port the most CPU consuming part of your application to VB.NET and compare.

Comment: VB6 was compiled, with the same optimizer as the Microsoft C++ compiler. It was a compiler option.

Answer (score 1):

The same algorithm will perform faster in VB6, because it is compiled in native language.
If the program has extensive memory allocation, it may perform faster in a .NET when running in a 64 bit environment though.